# backgroundColor for pushed view controller

Tags: ios, pushviewcontroller

I am pushing a viewcontroller (using a .xib) using:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController
                                         animated:YES];
```

I have the background color set to black in Interface builder, but I still see the default iOS gray background when the app is running. The black color shows up in the Interface builder when I look at the .xib file.

Can someone please help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to provide more information, like what your xib looks like, etc. Otherwise it's pretty hard to figure out what's wrong exactly. And I don't think iOS's default bg color is gray?

But you can set

```
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
```

in the `viewDidLoad:` of your `detailViewController` I guess.

Comment: Marking this as the accepted answer for pointing out that gray is not the default bg color and suggesting that it was coming from elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your input! It turns out a superclass was setting the background image to the default image. The solution turned out to be:

```
// Remove background image
[[[self.view subviews] objectAtIndex:0] removeFromSuperview];
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
```